# elastic search Sql query cannot be cancelled and long running

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I am unable to cancel the Elasticsearch sql query which is long running and I would like to know whether there is any option to make 'cancellable' true in the sql API.

```json
{
    "completed": false,
    "task": {
        "node": "5yiolpwu7l-nMcu3UoeUUg",
        "id": 56790064,
        "type": "transport",
        "action": "indices:data/read/sql",
        "description": "SQL [SELECT "product" AS "column1", "cursor" AS "column2" FROM "product_data" AS "cb3f008d95474444354567866"\r \r WHERE ( ( ("date" >= '2021-12-02' AND "date" <= '2022-02-28')) AND ( (CAST("product" AS VARCHAR) IN( 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'China' ))))\r GROUP BY "skills", "cursor"\r ORDER BY COUNT( DISTINCT "cursor" ) DESC, "column1" ASC, "column2" ASC LIMIT 1 ][null]",
        "start_time_in_millis": 1645698398116,
        "running_time_in_nanos": 496370826338275,
        "cancellable": false,
        "headers": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pleasec check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-async.html#sql-store-searches) documentation.

Comment: is this document help you ?